# Cannot open the AMPL IDE Window

Tags: ampl

I have obtained the AMPL trial license. I have followed all the instructions to download all the solvers. When I click on the amplide icon, it gives me the following message:

```
The Amplide executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the AMPL IDE package for OS X which should be fixed now. Please download the updated package from the [IDE Download page](http://ampl.com/products/ide/).